# Dynamically resize image in WebView

Tags: android, webview, android-webview, android-image

I found couple of question related this question on stackoverflow. I tried the solutions but that didn't worked. Here is my XML File:

```
<WebView
        android:id="@+id/detailsImage"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
```

**Details.java**

```
desImage.getSettings().setLayoutAlgorithm(LayoutAlgorithm.SINGLE_COLUMN);
desImage.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
desImage.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
desImage.loadUrl(url);
```

So, my question is how to dynamically resize image in WebView ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use javascript to dynamically manipulate the content shown in the WebView.

By default, JS is disabled inside WebView, you must enable it[1]

Once the content is loaded, you can execute JavaScript by calling WebView.loadUrl("javascript:").

Hope this helps.

[1] http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebSettings.html#setJavaScriptEnabled(boolean)